# send each element with class name via AJAX to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, element, each

Hi i'm using the below code to take data and send it to a php page, it works as i want it to but its only sending the first ".order" it comes across, ie. i need to send every element with class="order", would this be some sort of .each()?

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
                    var order=$('.order').html();
                    var dataString = 'order='+ order;

                    $.ajax
                        ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "order.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                            {
                                $("#response").html(html);
                            }
                        });
            });
```

Did this instead and it now works, bizarre!

```
$('#submit').live('click',function(){ 
                var order=$('.order').text();
                var dataString = 'order='+ order;

                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "order.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                        {
                            $("#response").html(html);
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `var order = $('form').serialize()` as explained here http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Other than this, you must do something like:

```
$('.order').each(function(){
    // Get values from order here... something like: order += $(this).html();
    // Also, note that if '.order' are inputs you should use $(this).val() instead of $(this).html();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it:

```
var order=$('.order')
   .map(function(){ return this.innerHtml; })
   .get().join('');
var dataString = 'order='+ order;
```

Comment: You need to encode the request.  The nicest way to do this is to do `var dataString = {"order": order};` and let jQuery handle the encoding.